# SQLite3 executemany incorrect number of bindings supplied. Claims I supplied 28 bindings no matter how many values is supply

Tags: python, sqlite

ive been at this for hours now,I have a list of 27 values I want to write in a row thebut no matter how long the list of values is it still complains about 28 values being supplied, I have tried other lengths of lists, supplying the list as a tuple, writing out the individual values into a tuple... just everything i could think of and still it complains about 28 values being supplied.

Weirdest of all when I make a table with 28 columns(for the supposed 28 values) and supply the same list it says is 28 values long, it suddenly complains about 57 values being supplied. here is my code with the a 5 variables long list.

```
import sqlite3
values = [' 19 850 000 Kč za nemovitost', ' včetně poplatků, včetně provize, včetně právního servisu', ' N6251', ' 29.09.2022', ' Cihlová']
def write(values):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(fr"C:\Users\halik\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\sws\code\test2.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print(sqlite3.version)
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ("Celková cena:", "Poznámka k ceně:", "ID zakázky:", "Aktualizace:", "Stavba:")''')
    except Error as e:  
        print(e)
        quit()
    print(f"values is {values}")
    print(f"len(values) is {len(values)}")
    print(f"len((values,)) is {len((values,))}")
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", values)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

write(values)
```

with this exact code above i get this output and error

```
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", values)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 28 supplied.
```

Comment: You have print statements in your code, but they're not in your output.

Comment: 28 is the length of `' 19 850 000 Kč za nemovitost'` and 57 is the length of `' včetně poplatků, včetně provize, včetně právního servisu'`. Use execute and not executemany.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. First the except Error, second the value on the INSERT command should be a tuple (values,) or alternative you can change the input list of tuples to `values = [('19 850 000 Kč za nemovitost', 'včetně poplatků, včetně provize, včetně právního servisu', 'N6251', '29.09.2022', 'Cihlová')]`. In this case you can use only `values` into the insert command:
(- A space in front of an entry is not recommended, also the spaces and colon into the column name)

```
import sqlite3
values = [('19 850 000 Kč za nemovitost', 'včetně poplatků, včetně provize, včetně právního servisu', 'N6251', '29.09.2022', 'Cihlová')]
def write(values):
    try:
        #conn = sqlite3.connect(fr"C:\Users\halik\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\sws\code\test2.db")
        conn = sqlite3.connect("test2.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print(sqlite3.version)
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (Celkova_cena, Poznamka_k_cene, ID_zakazky, Aktualizace, Stavba)""")
    except Exception as e:  # not Error as e
        print(e)
        #quit()
    print(f"values is {values}")
    print(f"len(values) is {len(values)}")
    print(f"len((values,)) is {len((values,))}")
    cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO test (Celkova_cena, Poznamka_k_cene, ID_zakazky, Aktualizace, Stavba) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", values) #Insert tuple of values
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

write(values)
```

Output in [DB-Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/):
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick suggestions after implementing them it ran without error but nothing was writen to the database - a table was created however there are no columns or values in there and i cant figure out why that is the case. any ideas?

Comment: Have you adjust your path and DB name?